# watchkit image asset naming convention

Tags: ios, watchkit

Is there a standard naming convention for watchkit image assets so that when you import them into an xcassets folder they are categorized correctly?

I've tried

```
    watchimage@2x~watch.png
    watchimage@2x~38mm.png
    watchimage~watch@2x.png
    watchimage~38mm@2x.png
```

none of which worked.

currently, its a lot of work to drag a bunch of `38mm` images into the media asset, set them all to device specific "Apple Watch" then drag all them to the correct slot, then rinse and repeat for the `42mm` images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, unfortunately. Hopefully this is something Apple will support in the future. We ended up writing an Automator script to handle the imports for us.

I'd recommend filing an `Enhancement` radar on Apple's [bug reporting system](http://bugreport.apple.com).